# OSX Mavericks C compiler not working (linker command failed)

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, osx-mavericks

A while ago I installed osx-gcc-installer. It hasn't been an issue until I tried to install opencv with homebrew. Brew doctor complained about osx-gcc-installer so I uninstalled command line tools, xcode and every sign of osx-gcc-installer.

Now when I install xcode again as well as the command line tools I keep getting the same errors. Here is the output of trying to install webp (which my brew doctor says I need). Any help is much appreciated:

terminal output

```
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And the config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libwebp configure 0.4.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-libwebpmux --enable-libwebpdemux --enable-libwebpdecoder --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/webp/0.4.0_1

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Jons-MacBook-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.2.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 170 tasks, 947 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.66, Mach factor: 2.32
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3
PATH: /usr/local/opt/libpng/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2296: checking build system type
configure:2310: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
configure:2330: checking host system type
configure:2343: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
configure:2363: checking target system type
configure:2376: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
configure:2418: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2486: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2497: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2547: result: yes
configure:2688: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2727: result: ./install-sh -c -d
configure:2740: checking for gawk
configure:2770: result: no
configure:2740: checking for mawk
configure:2770: result: no
configure:2740: checking for nawk
configure:2770: result: no
configure:2740: checking for awk
configure:2756: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2767: result: awk
configure:2778: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2800: result: yes
configure:2893: checking for style of include used by make
configure:2921: result: GNU
configure:2992: checking for gcc
configure:3019: result: clang
configure:3248: checking for C compiler version
configure:3257: clang --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
configure:3268: $? = 0
configure:3257: clang -v >&5
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
configure:3268: $? = 0
configure:3257: clang -V >&5
clang: error: unsupported option '-V -isystem/usr/local/include'
configure:3268: $? = 1
configure:3257: clang -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
configure:3268: $? = 1
configure:3288: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3310: clang    conftest.c  >&5
ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3314: $? = 1
configure:3352: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libwebp"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libwebp"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libwebp 0.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://code.google.com/p/webp/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://developers.google.com/speed/webp"
| #define PACKAGE "libwebp"
| #define VERSION "0.4.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3357: error: in `/private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0':
configure:3359: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=clang
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE='#'
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_CFLAGS=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_V=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='awk'
BUILD_GIF2WEBP_FALSE=''
BUILD_GIF2WEBP_TRUE=''
BUILD_LIBWEBPDECODER_FALSE=''
BUILD_LIBWEBPDECODER_TRUE=''
BUILD_VWEBP_FALSE=''
BUILD_VWEBP_TRUE=''
CC='clang'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GIF_INCLUDES=''
GIF_LIBS=''
GL_INCLUDES=''
GL_LIBS=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
JPEG_INCLUDES=''
JPEG_LIBS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPNG_CONFIG=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='./install-sh -c -d'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libwebp'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://code.google.com/p/webp/issues'
PACKAGE_NAME='libwebp'
PACKAGE_STRING='libwebp 0.4.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libwebp'
PACKAGE_URL='http://developers.google.com/speed/webp'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.4.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PNG_INCLUDES=''
PNG_LIBS=''
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
TIFF_INCLUDES=''
TIFF_LIBS=''
USE_EXPERIMENTAL_CODE=''
USE_SWAP_16BIT_CSP=''
VERSION='0.4.0'
WANT_DEMUX_FALSE=''
WANT_DEMUX_TRUE=''
WANT_MUX_FALSE=''
WANT_MUX_TRUE=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='clang'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
ax_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin13.2.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin13.2.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /private/tmp/webp-Rsgs/libwebp-0.4.0/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(top_builddir)/./install-sh -c -d'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgconfigdir=''
prefix='/usr/local/Cellar/webp/0.4.0_1'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin13.2.0'
target_vendor='apple'
```

EDIT:
After some more investigating I think I might have an issue with my /usr/bin/ld:

```
$ /usr/bin/ld
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specificed, assuming 10.7
ld: no object files specified for inferred architecture x86_64
```

Operating Systems isn't my strong suit so i might be off topic. Hoping this helps someone with more OS knowledge.

EDIT2:

Attempting to compile the test code from the config.log output results in the following:

```
jon$ clang -o test ~/Desktop/test.c -v
    Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
    Thread model: posix
     "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name test.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -fdebug-compilation-dir /usr/bin -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 116 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.9.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/5s/5jxchdtd3pvc09rwdt4n2nfw0000gn/T/test-309e3a.o -x c /Users/jon/Desktop/test.c
    clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/local/include
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
     /usr/include
     /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
     /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
    End of search list.
     "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -o test /var/folders/5s/5jxchdtd3pvc09rwdt4n2nfw0000gn/T/test-309e3a.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
    ld: can't open output file for writing: test, errno=13 for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

jon$ gcc -o test ~/Desktop/test.c 
ld: can't open output file for writing: test, errno=13 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
jon$
```

Comment: Did you check the 100 or so questions with the title `error: C compiler cannot create executables`? My guess is that they'll help. If you did, you should add what you've tried.

Comment: Yes I read all 100 or so of them. The vast majority of them say to just install the most current Xcode command line tools. I have done that many times as well as uninstalled Xcode before installing the command line tools. No matter what I still get the same output above with what look like clang linker errors

Comment: Have you tried manually compiling the test code from the config log? (The portion just before the line "configure:3357: error: ...") There is always the (remote) possibility that the `webp` homebrew formula has a bug.

Comment: Added the results of trying to run that in the question above. The 'linker command failed...' makes me feel like the linker (which I thought was the /usr/bin/ld but I could be wrong) is my issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a bizarre situation, and certainly one I've never run into before specifically. I *have* seen problems with `ld`, especially after Xcode 5.x, and some older/alternative architectures. So, it is far from ideal, but I wouldn't doubt that the following related workarounds might get you up and running.

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/1939

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3406578

Comment: I tried the `export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'` command and homebrew still gives me an error that the C compiler does not work and cannot create executables.